# How to change e-mail address on Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to change e-mail address on Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow sites such that the content is not deleted?

Comment: What email addresses?  The one on your profile or email addresses in posts?

Comment: @NathanOliver, When you create a profile, you have to create e-mail address and password. Is it possible to change the existing e-mail address on the same profile with another one?

Comment: You should be able to change login information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/4510943)